# How write data-remote="true" when using createElement in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating form using `createElement()` in **ReactJSX**.

My code looks like this:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');

form.id = "new_message_form";
form.method = 'post';
form.className = 'chat_input';
```

I want to use `data-remote="true"` in this form (it should be something like this:

```
form.data-remote="true";
```

Can anybody advise how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no standard attribute like `data-remote` or `remote` in html forms, it's just custom attribute that is related to rails specificly.

Docs on data-* attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

So, to set that attribute, you need to set this attribute explicitly:

```
form.setAttribute("data-remote", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

JSX

```
<form id="new_message_form" method="post" className="chat_input" data-remote="true"/>
```

desugared to JS

```
React.createElement("form", { id: "new_message_form", method: "post", className: "chat_input", "data-remote": "true" })
```

You can use JSX online in the Babel REPL to see if it gets compiled to what you need: http://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Thank you for fast respond. I generate this form using mentioned format. 
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.id = "new_message_form";
form.method = 'post';
form.className = 'chat_input'; and I just want to add to this form data-remote="true"; (when I'm using form.dataRemote = 'true' it's not working.) After that code will look : document.getElementsByClassName('chat_windows')[0].appendChild(div).appendChild(form).appendChild(input1);
document.getElementsByClassName('chat_windows')[0].appendChild(div).appendChild(form).appendChild(input2); Code will create my form onClick...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with setting attribute directly to form. 
Code: **form.setAttribute("data-remote", "true");**